# Android: Open existing PDF file check and fill checkbox fields and then save a new version of the document

Tags: android, pdf, android-api-levels

I need to programmatically edit a PDF file that already exist like the image below. How can I "Open" this document, "Draw" and then "Save" An edited version of this PDF?
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Used the iText library incorporated the Android Project.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("sdcard/local_pdf.pdf");
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
        new FileOutputStream("sdcard/local_pdf_fill.pdf"));
content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);
content.beginText();
content.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "STRING HERE", x, y, 0);
//max X = 800, max Y = 600, 0 = rotation
```